# How to solve a puzzle using breadth first search?

Tags: c++, graph, artificial-intelligence, puzzle, breadth-first-search

I took a class on this a few semesters ago, but I didn't learn much at the time. I watched a lecture by MIT on Breadth First Search. I learned quite a bit from it, however it only taught me that BFS is a good algorithm for searching a graph, awesome. I need to solve a puzzle.

So I wrote the puzzle in C++, but now I need to figure out a way for the computer to solve it. From what I understand, I will have to have the computer generate all the states for this puzzle into a graph then have the computer use BFS to find the solved state? How can I calculate how many vertices and edges my puzzle has? The puzzle I am talking about is the "Cracker Barrel Triangle Game." Any help would be appreciated on how to solve this bad boy.

Sorry I failed to mention how the puzzle works. So you are given a triangle with 14 pegs and 15 locations, looks similar to this:

```
    * 
   2 3 
  4 5 6 
 7 8 9 A 
B C D E F
```

where the * is the empty space. Now, kinda like checkers, you can only jump a peg over another peg to the empty space, so there is only two valid moves here, 4 to 1, or, 6 to 1, the middle peg is removed, resulting in this:

```
    1 
   2 * 
  4 5 * 
 7 8 9 A 
B C D E F
```

after jumping peg 6 to 1

You continue to do this until only one peg is left on the board.

Comment: Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself. See SSCCE.org for guidance.

Comment: I just want to know the process of solving puzzles with a computer.

Comment: Can you describe what the puzzle is? Most of us won't have heard of this problem and can't give any useful feedback without knowing what it is.

Comment: Almost certainly you are wrong to have the computer generate the graph. The graph is notional, it doesn't have to be explicitly represented as a data structure in the computer memory.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the standard approach to a state-space search problem like this:

**Create a function that can generate the next possible states:**
This function needs to  be able to take in some sort of information representing the board and return a list of moves that could potentially be made (or boards that would result from them). You might, for instance, iterate over each peg, calculate the moves that that given peg could make, and append them to a list until you've checked all of them.

**Use BFS to generate/search graph:**
Initialize the current node to the start state, and then start the breadth-first search. For each node, calculate the next possible states and add them to the end of your search queue. Keep a dictionary (because it's more efficient than a list) of every state that you've already added to the queue. If you generate one that is in the dictionary, discard it instead of editing it. Eventually, you will get to a board that only has 1 peg, at which point your search will have been successful.

This is the standard approach to solving a puzzle with breadth-first search. You don't need to know how many vertices and edges there are in advance, because your code will generate the graph as it goes. Note that it won't automatically generate a complete graph of the state space. In order to do that, you would need to add an edge every time you came upon a duplicate board state.